# Dependency Injection: Pattern and Naming for a Collection of Fuctions

Tags: go, dependency-injection, naming

I'm developing a framework in Go where I let the user inject dependencies like a logger and a database. I provide interfaces for these that I expect the user to implement.

Now I also need the user to provide a bunch of functions, like signature verification and hashing, because I don't want to choose a specific implementation for it. See the following (unrealistic) example

```golang
package crypto

type Fns interface {
    // Hash returns the hash digest of the passed data
    Hash([]byte) []byte
    // Verify checks for a valid signature on the message for given public key
    Verify(msg, sig []byte, pk PublicKey) (bool, error)
}
```

So this `crypto.Fns` interface is just a collection of functions. I expect the user to implement it as a stateless `struct{}` type. I also *don't* want to save it to a package global variable and just wrap the calls like so

```golang
package crypto

// user must set this before using the framework
var Impl Fns

func Hash(data []byte) []byte { return Impl.Hash(data) }
// ...
```

because at a later point in time it might become interesting to use different implementations at different places in the framework.

Do you think this is a good pattern? If so, how should I name this thing? `Fns`? `Helper`? `Impl`?

Comment: "It might become interesting to use different implementations at different places in the framework." Then a package variable obviously doesn't work because you can only supply a single implementation. Aside: the standard library already defines a [Hash interface](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash). With your version you force users to write quite a bit of standard code.

Comment: That's why I say in the second part that I don't want to save it to a package variable.
I know about the `hash.Hash` interface. It is an example and will probably look different in my case.

Comment: You might want to look into the dargo framework for dependency injection.  We have now used it in several real cloud projects.  It makes things like unit testing a breeze and has other DI friendly properties as well.  Disclaimer: my team and I wrote the framework, so... this is like self-promotion.  https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo

Comment: @jwells131313 it looks quite impressive! How would you handle the particular use case I described? You might want to post it as an answer.